# Api gateway still pointing to the old lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I have an API gateway with websocket

```yaml
  WebSocket:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Api
    Properties:
      ProtocolType: WEBSOCKET
      RouteSelectionExpression: "$request.body.action"
      Name: !Sub ${Appname}-${Environment}

  WebSocketStage:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Stage
    Properties:
      StageName: !Ref Environment
      AutoDeploy: true
      ApiId: !Ref WebSocket
```

before that, I had a function `onConnect` attached to the API, but since I discovered that it was not necessary, I have remove from my Cloudformation stack. However now my Websocket is not working anymore.

I have enabled Cloudwatch logs for API Gateway and I have discovered that the route `onConnect` is still pointing to the old lambda, which does not exist anymore

```
2020-05-31T19:09:56.014+07:00
(nnnnnnnnnn=) WebSocket Request Route: [$connect]

2020-05-31T19:09:56.014+07:00
(nnnnnnn=) Client [UserAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36, SourceIp: 115.73.134.142] is connecting to WebSocket API

2020-05-31T19:09:56.014+07:00
(nnnnnn=) Endpoint request URI: https://lambda.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-1:11111111111:function:api-development-onConnectWebsocket-GGGGGGGGG/invocations <-------------------- OLD LAMBDA

2020-05-31T19:09:56.030+07:00
(nnnnnnnn=) Execution failed due to configuration error: Invalid permissions on Lambda function
```

In console nothing is showed, the `$connect` route is removed, so what is going on here? Unfortunately I wasn't able to figure it out, **because the actual function does not exist and in console is pointing to the new one.**

Can someone help?

Thanks

Comment: Have you deployed the changes? Maybe you keep executing old version of the api?

Comment: I am using Cloudformation, every time I do some changes I re-deploy the entire stack. Also I checked for drifting in my stack, but everything was in sync

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are deploying your changes with cloudformation, but within api gateway you need to create a deployment for the changes you've made to go live.

You can test this by using the console to deploy your api gateway stage. You can learn a little more about api gateway deployment in cloudformation here: https://currentlyunnamed-theclassic.blogspot.com/2018/12/mastering-cloudformation-for-api.html

Comment: thanks for the answer, however I don't think that's the case, I tried to deploy the API manually and it was still pointing to the same function

Comment: Also I am not sure this is relevant, but I am using `Autodeploy` set to `true`.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigatewayv2-stage.html#cfn-apigatewayv2-stage-autodeploy